# how do i benchmark mysql in wamp?

Tags: php, mysql, benchmarking, wamp

I'm about to deploy a college website. It has around 2200 user profiles generated - one for every student- so i decided to gauge the server load and capacity. Problem is I cant figure out how exactly to do it- on my development machine i use WAMPserver. Is it alright if we host it on WAMP on production side as well or should we switch?

And if WAMP is alright, then how do you recommend we benchmark MySQL?

Comment: Benching mysql alone isn't a valid test. You have to consider Apache's performance as well. MySQL could be tuned to hum along at Warp 10, but if Apache's misconfigured, the whole system could crawl along like a snail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with benchmarking the entire setup, if possible on the production machines.

One simple tool is the [Apache jMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) that allows you to have parallel users, ramp up periods and loads of reports. It isn't super easy but just follow any tutorial and you should be up and running fast.

Run the tests from another machine on the network to get a better test of speed including network delays.

If you find the performance good enough then there is no need for detailed tests of Apache or MySQL.

Comment: @andreas-weberbrand Fantastic! Thanks! I guess I need to do a little more homework before I can start using jMeter. The documentation is a little intimidating. do you used it to test your servers too?

Comment: It can be used for many things and I use it to test old vs new code (on major refactorings), how much logging/debugging costs and how many users sites can handle.

Answer (score 1):

A good tool to benchmark MySQL is [mysqlslap](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlslap.html) but as other has pointed out, you may want to do a complete benchmark to detect strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: What do you recommend for a complete benchmark? Do you have a standard checklist I can have a peek at? Thanks a heap for pointing out mysqlslap!